# Do SSL certificates for email auto renew?

Tags: email, ssl-certificate

On my mac, I looked at the Mail Connection Doctor and one of the things I noticed was an expiration date for my Parallel Panel self-signed root certificate.

Is that something I have to renew or does it auto renew itself?

I'm using a virtual dedicated server and didn't buy the certificate, it was there by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question right away: No these certificates do not auto-renew. You would have to renew the certificate yourself or create a new self signed certificate on this machine (e.g. via `openssl`).

What you have to keep in mind however, is that an expired certificate will not lead to your website stopping to work - there will simply be a warning that the certificate is expired and you have to confirm this before the page loads. As you are using a self-signed certificate right now you already should receive a certificate warning - so even if the certificate expires nothing changes for you.

Comment: When a self-signed certificate expires, does that mean it's no longer secure ?

Comment: No not per se. The certificate expiry exists to create a limit how long a certificate can be valid (given it is not revoked by the CA before). This ensures that you do not have any certificates that would be valid forever. This could be a risk if you lose the certificate/private key. Take for example someone gets access to old (expired) certificate from paypal.com and they plan to use it to phish data - your browser would warn you that this certificate is expired and you'd know something is wrong. this has absolutely nothing to do with the encryption - this is still working fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate it yourself after it expires.

Answer (score 0):

They cert probably won't renew on its own. If this if your account/server, check with the VPS server provider to see what their process is.